# What's another way to say "incorporate multiple influences"?

Tags: phrases

Recently I was working on a paper which talks about a certain musician's incorporation of multiple styles and influences.....

Is there a more concise way to say "incorporate multiple influences"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclectic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclectic) has the connotations of containing/being influenced by a variety of genres.

Comment: You should really quote a [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclectic) of the word, as well as provide a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Often the word "***fusion***" is used to describe combined influences in various endeavors.

It was used alone to denote a combination of jazz and rock  music which became popular in the 1970's-'80's - but, would not be out of place describing the melding of other styles of music.

Answer (score 0):

The word synthesis is a perfect match here:

> **[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synthesis)**
>
> **Synthesis:** The combination of components or elements to form a connected whole.
>   ‘the synthesis of intellect and emotion in his work’

Here’s a paragraph of some music related text ([source](http://www.africanamericanmusicnc.com/about-the-music/music-styles/)) that demonstrates it well:

> *The blues became marked as a distinctive musical genre around the turn of the 20th century, developing throughout the Southeast as a **synthesis** of the African American music traditions which preceded it, including work songs, field hollers, dance tunes, minstrel songs, and spirituals.*